# Error: Could not find or load main class Hello2

Tags: java

I'm just learning java and following a book.

I have a program written via text editor and run commands via cmd.

I've complied 1 program thru javac and executed thru java no problem. (Hello)
Then I modified that to add a comment to the class, named file Hello2.java. I compiled it with no problems, but upon execution, I receive this error: Could not find or load main class Hello2.

I have classpath and path set correct;y on environment variables.

Ideas?

UPDATE

Hello.java

```
  public class Hello {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello, world!");
      }
  }
```

Hello2.java

```
//Filename Hello2.java
//Written by 
//Written on 

public class Hello2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}

/*This class demonstrates the use of the println() method to print the message Hello, world! */
```

Comment: Did you rename the class inside of the file as well?

Comment: Provide your class here, it will make things easy for everyone.

Comment: @user1152552 : Any update on my query??? Let me know if you don't need help... OK??

Comment: both of them are working perfectly at my end... so what is problem??

Comment: @user1152552 : Please see my updated  answer.. Is that what are you doing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. I know it's not a code problem. But what I did is that I deleted CLASSPATH from system variables and everything now works...at least for now.

Thanks a lot everyone for your inputs, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of the public class too when you change the name of the file. So, if your file is called `Hello2.java`, the class should be called `Hello2` and not `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have Hello2.java file as below.

```
class Hello {
     public static void main (String args[]) {
     System.out.println("Hello");
     }
}
```

Change it to

```
class Hello2 {
     public static void main (String args[]) {
     System.out.println("Hello");
     }
}
```

The change is `class Hello2` instead of `class Hello`.

**Note** : You should always have classname and file name SAME.

Good Luck!!!

**Update 1**

Are you doing below steps??

1. Wrote Hello.java
2. Compile by javac Hello.java
3. Run by java Hello
4. Rename Hello.java to Hello2.java
5. Rename class name i.e. `class Hello` to `class Hello2`
6. javac Hello2.java
7. java Hello2

I believe you are missing Step 6 & executing step 7 after step 5. Please confirm.

Comment: I've already changed accordingly and got that error. In addition, when I ran java Hello (the 1st one that worked), now doesn't and gives me the same error..,

Comment: update question and provide Java code of `Hello2.java` and `Hello.java` files. I need both...

Comment: ...and you need to invoke `javac` and `java` wuith the appropriate classname - everything needs to be consistent

Comment: Hi Fahim, that's what I did with your steps. Now I'm redoing your steps with the existing files. In step 3 I get the same error.

Comment: this is impossible... after compiling (javac Hello.java) you should be able to run javac Hello... can u send me screenshot of the command prompt for the same at parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in as you don't have permission to add image on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set the classpath correctly? Why don't you try running java -cp *the directory of the .class file* Hello ? If that doesn't work please upload the full stacktrace.

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled Java from system and reinstalled it. Deleted the compiled java files redid everything. Also, did the CLASSPATH and PATH in variables, I still get the same error. However, after doing "java -cp . Hello", the output worked! So I don't know if there's something wrong with settings or system, or do have to wright -cp command everytime?

Comment: Did you enter the classpath system variable exactly as you did when you ran java -cp?

Comment: Yes. I went with this:     C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin

Comment: I've deleted CLASSPATH from system variables and everything now works...at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you add the location of your `.class` file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add `.` to your classpath.
Note that the windows classpath separator is a semi-colon ie `;`

If your class file is saved in following directory with `Hello2` program name
`d:\sample`

1. `java -cp d:\sample Hello2`
2. `java -cp . Hello2`